# Prove that the union of closed subsets of X is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $F_n \subseteq P(X)$ be a sequence of closed subsets of $X$. Suppose that for each $x \in X$, there exists some $r>0$ so that $B(x,r)$ intersects at most a finite number of the sets $F_n$. Prove that ${\bigcup}^{\infty}_{n=0} F_n$ is closed.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at rudin...

Comment: This is a useful result and applies for all types of topological spaces, in this form: A  family $F$ of subsets of a space $X$ is locally finite iff every $p\in X$ has a nbhd $U_p$ such that $\{f\in F:f\cap U_p\ne \emptyset\}$ is finite.  Now if $F$ is a locally finite family of  subsets then (1) $\{\bar f: f\in F\}$ is locally finite and (2) $\cup \{\bar f : f\in F\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty F_n$. Suppose $x_m \in \mathcal{F}$ converges to $x \in X$. We must show $x \in \mathcal{F}$.

Pick some arbitrary value of $\varepsilon > 0$; I'm going to pick $\varepsilon = 99$. Since $x_m \to x$, there exists some $M$ such that
$$m \ge M \implies d(x_m, x) < 99 \implies x_m \in B(x; 99) \cap \mathcal{F}.$$
From our hypothesis, there exist finitely many integers $n_1, \ldots, n_k$ such that
\begin{align*}
B(x; 99) \cap \mathcal{F} &= B(x; 99) \cap (F_{n_1} \cup \ldots \cup F_{n_k}) \\
&= (B(x; 99) \cap F_{n_1}) \cup \ldots \cup (B(x; 99) \cap F_{n_k}).
\end{align*}
Therefore, the sequence $(x_m)_{m\ge M}$ lies entirely in $(B(x; 99) \cap F_{n_1}) \cup \ldots \cup (B(x; 99) \cap F_{n_k})$.

By the pigeonhole principle, infinitely many points of $x_m$ lie in one of the unioned sets. That is, there exists some $1 \le i \le k$ such that $B(x; 99) \cap F_{n_i}$ (and hence $F_{n_i}$) contains a subsequence of $x_m$.

Such a subsequence is convergent, and converges to $x$. However, it's contained entirely in the closed set $F_{n_i}$, which implies $x \in F_{n_i} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, completing the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ an element of the complementary space of $\cup_nF_n$, there exists a $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\cap \cup_nF_n=B(x,r)\cap F_{i_1}\cup...\cup B(x,r)\cap F_{i_n}$.

Since $x$ is in the complementary of $F_{i_j}$ and $F_{i_j}$ is closed there exists $r_j$ such that $B(x,r_j)$ is in the complementary of $F_{i_j}$. Let $s=inf (r,r_{i_j}j=1,..,n)$

$B(x,s)$ is in the complementary space of $\cup_nF_n$.

Comment: My edit was only for a missing space in the last line.